# how to check if the date is a Saturday (or end of the week) using php

Tags: php

I am just trying to run a script that will add the up everything from a column in my MySQL database for each week. Right now I am trying to have php check if the date is a saturday, then it will take the last 6 days (rows) from the database and add the rows under the column (which is numerical) together. Is there an easier way to add everything together from one week? if not, how would I check to see if the date (row) is a Saturday?
EDIT:
My database structure is:
    id
    date
    total_miles
    comment
the total_miles column is    int    and that is what I need to add together for each week by checking if the    date    is a saturday

Comment: Show us your query as it is right now.  Also, why do this in PHP?  Why not do it in-query?

Comment: need more details regarding your question. Maybe you should also provide your database structure

Comment: *"Is there an easier way to add everything together from one week?"* - Show us your way first.

Comment: I can't figure out how to add code to my question...

Comment: You might want to create the table in SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ then paste the URL into your question. That way we can try things directly with your schema/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek:

```
 DAYOFWEEK(date)

Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index     values correspond to the ODBC standard.

mysql> SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03');
        -> 7
```

If I wanted to group things together based on the weekday, I might use:

```
SELECT SUM(total_miles) FROM tablename GROUP BY WEEK(id);
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

ADDITIONAL:

You can select the WEEK(id) or DAYOFWEEK(id) in your select statement, for later use in PHP.

If you want to do the same in php (in general, do things in SQL if you can, but there are odd cases), you can do the same using the php `date` command - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php (this assumes you have the date as a unix timestamp; if not read on further down).

You can use the format of 'D' to get the NAME of the day of the week, 'N' or 'w' to get the NUMBER of the day of the week, or 'W' to get the week NUMBER in the year.

If you have the date as a DateTime, or as text (which can be easily converted to DateTime), you can use DateTime::format - see the examples on http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php - the $format parameter is the same as the one to the date function above.

Comment: if I was using php to get that from my database how would I do it. because your answer is in SQL. I can get a row from a database with php but how would you do it if it is a function?

Comment: can you answer my question from the comment above? I can do the select statement with the dayofweek('2007-02-03') and sum(total_miles), but how do you use mysql_fetch_assoc to get the data from the row if it is in the dayofweek function?

Comment: I've added it to my answer, under "Additional" - two different options

Answer (score 0):

`date("l",$timestamp)` or `date("w",$timestamp)` can check the day of week in PHP.

if it's mysql database date format, you might use `date("w",strtotime($date))` to know the day of week.

please see :[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)